# Is it possible to choose the S3 directory I want to store my pipeline run files?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

My pipeline run directories are being created in my defaul bucket dir and it is getting messy.
I've been trying to set a subdirectory in my s3 default bucket to store all my pipeline run directories (PreProcess, Train, Evaluate, Interpret...) but I haven't suceeded yet. Can someone help me to do that, please?

I've tried changing my step name from CrossPreprocess-Data to sagemaker/cross-project/CrossPreprocess-Data and it worked. It created my pipeline directories inside the dir sagemaker/cross-project

```
    step_process = ProcessingStep(
        name="sagemaker/cross-project/CrossPreprocess-Data",
        processor=sklearn_processor,
        outputs=[
            ProcessingOutput(output_name="train", source="/opt/ml/processing/train"),
            ProcessingOutput(output_name="validation", source="/opt/ml/processing/val"),
            ProcessingOutput(output_name="test", source="/opt/ml/processing/test"),
            ProcessingOutput(output_name="metafiles", source="/opt/ml/processing/metafiles"),
        ],
        code=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "preprocess.py"),
        job_arguments=["--input-data", input_data, "--run-datetime", run_datetime, "--project-name", project_name],
    )
```

BUT, on the next step, I got this error and I couldn't move on with my execution

```
ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the UpdatePipeline operation: Unable to parse pipeline definition. Invalid property reference 'Steps.sagemaker/cross-project/CrossPreprocess-Data.ProcessingOutputConfig.Outputs['train'].S3Output.S3Uri' in GetFunction definition.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the destination in the `ProcessingOutput` to specify where in the S3 bucket your files should be saved to.

https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/processing.html#sagemaker.processing.ProcessingOutput

Comment: thanks for the reply, Kirit! but this still didn't solve my issue. When I execute pipeline.upsert(role_arn=role), the PreProcess dir with my preprocess.py is still created in my default bucket :(

Comment: Same feedback, specifying the `destination` param for ProcessingOutput only uploads the output file to that specific s3 location, but inputs are still automatically uploaded to the base bucket. Looking for a Pipeline definition or config for organizing uploads if what I'm thinking is also needed for managing the inputs too

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple steps to take to manage where files are uploaded during a sagemaker Pipeline run:

1. **Outputs**: When specifying outputs for a `ProcessingStep`, [add the `destination` param to `ProcessingOutput`](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/processing.html#sagemaker.processing.ProcessingOutput) to tell the job where to upload the final output to on s3

```
ProcessingOutput(
    output_name="train", 
    source="/opt/ml/processing/train", 
    destination=f"s3://{sagemaker_session.default_bucket()}/project_folder/outputs"
)
```

Note that if you rerun the job using the same destination, the outputs WILL OVERWRITE the previous outputs at that destination unless appending a unique identifier like the job id to the destination path.

2. **Inputs**: We also need to manage where the inputs will be uploaded. We can do this by adding a [bucket prefix to our `PipelineSession` object](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/workflows/pipelines/sagemaker.workflow.pipelines.html#sagemaker.workflow.pipeline_context.PipelineSession) wherever we pass a `sagemaker_session`. Do this by setting `default_bucket_prefix` to whatever new folder under your default bucket you want to use:

When instantiating a processor to later pass into a `ProcessingStep`...

```
processor = ScriptProcessor(
    command=['python3'],
    image_uri="[your aws account id].dkr.ecr.[region].amazonaws.com/[ecr repository name]",
    role="[role arn]",
    instance_count=1,
    instance_type='ml.m5.4xlarge',
    sagemaker_session=PipelineSession(default_bucket_prefix="pipeline-job-runs")
)
```

or when instantiating an estimator to later pass into a `TrainingStep`...

```
estimator = PyTorch(
    entry_point="fine_tune.py",
    source_dir="src/train",
    base_job_name="project-folder/training",
    instance_type="ml.g5.12xlarge",
    instance_count=1,
    role="[role arn]",
    py_version="py310",
    framework_version="2.1.0",
    hyperparameters={
        'model_id': model_id,
        'per_device_train_batch_size': 1,
    },
    sagemaker_session=PipelineSession(default_bucket_prefix="pipeline-job-runs")
)
```